# Linux VPS red5 stop issue

Tags: linux, red5

I have godaddy linux vps centos 6.0 server. I have installed red5 there. I am start or stop red5 from my linux terminal pc. when i close my teminal. red5 stopped working. if my terminal open then red5 working good. please suggest solution after starting red5 if i close my terminal red5 should not stop working.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run the red5 server in background not in the terminal. So you need to run this command **nohup ./red5.sh &**, this will run the red5 server even you closed the terminal. I have used this command for ubuntu server please check for cent os.

Thanks,
Mohamedh Nishadh